# Tags: format or formats?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

There are two tags, `format` and `formats`, which should probably be merged. I suggest keeping it under the name `format` or renaming it to `formatting` because they can be used as verbs to describe the process of formatting.

(I don't know where to post these kinds of things or how to inform moderators about them, so could somebody tell me if there is a better way to bring up these topics? Thanks.)

Comment: Thank you for the migration :)

Comment: I just read the meta post on tag-synonym-request and tag-removal-request. Until this post is obsolete, those two tags should be used in meta questions to merge and remove tags; respectively.